# Generate df with all possible combinations of values

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have 3 columns (A,B,C), the value of which can vary from 0 to 100, in increments of 0.1. How to generate df with all possible combinations of values ​​of these columns? :

```
A   B   C
0   0   0
0   0   0.01
0   0   0.02
…   …   … and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It's not combinations but a [product](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

<s>You could use [combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)</s>

```py
import itertools

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Python range does not work with floats
my_range = np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01)
combinations = itertools.product(my_range, repeat=3)
df = pd.DataFrame(combinations)
```

Comment: I made a mistake, it's not combinations you want but a product. See a working example here: https://repl.it/repls/AcceptableYummyEvent